# Local.xml being ignored

Tags: layout, xml

Magento 1.9.x was reading layouts fine from my `local.xml` layout file.

After installing some extensions Magento is now ignoring `local.xml` and is reading from `responsive.xml` instead.

Is there a way of changing this back to how it was?

Comment: which extensions did you installed ?

Comment: I didnt install the extensions, the client did. They are unsure as to what was added (someone else did it for them, and now I have to fix it). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check if any of that module has re-write for method `getFileLayoutUpdatesXml` from `Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update` class.